# Import existing recurring donations into Paypal

Tags: paypal, donations

Currently I am working with several non-profits (who receive recurring donations normally monthly) to migrate away from their current gateways to Paypal.

Is there any way to import their currently donor's payment information into Paypal? 
If not which would you recommend to help migrate their donors over?

1) Setup a special section of their website and as donor's to re-subscribe?
or 
2) Send out Invoices for their current recurring amount (if its possible to email a subscription)?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what type of system you are currently using, and specifically what type of service you are going to use from PayPal.  Are you going to be using PayPal's Recurring Payments, Enhanced Recurring Payments, Subscriptions or Payflow's Recurring Billing?  If you have all of the contributor's information, such as credit card info, name, address and etc and you are going to be using PayPal's Recurring Payments or Payflow's Recurring Billing you could use the API's to create the profiles on your PayPal or Payflow account without having to have the contributor do anything on their end.  If you are going to be using PayPal's Enhanced Recurring Payments or Subscriptions, then you would need the buyer to re sign up for a recurring donation.  You can could use either option that you mentioned above.  You would be able to do either through PayPal.

Comment: Clearly I need to look more closely at the paypal options. Any ideas of clear documentation I could refer to? Paypal tend to be a little roundabout.

Comment: Most docs are going to be found at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/ and some are still available at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides until everything is moved off of x.com and moved over to the new developer.paypal.com site.